# List 2 folders using a single command

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0

Assume I have 2 folders A and B

```
Folder A contains files like "food.txt", "drinks.txt", ...
Folder B contains files like "beverage.txt", "entre.txt",...
```

Is there a way using dir (gci) or any command to get an output like

```
"beverage.txt", "drinks.txt", "entre.txt", "food.txt",..
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

`-File` will list only files
`-Recurse` will also get all folder under the given one

`Select-Object -Expandproperty Name` will give you only the filename

---

If the files are located somewhere completely different you can just give `GCI`multiple Paths:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path "PathToFolderA","PathToFolderB" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: The file argument is giving me " a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name file

Comment: @user10191234 What Powershell Version are you using (You should probaly update if it is not PS 5.0)? I don't remember in which option `-File` was introduced but in the current version it works as expected.

Comment: @Paxz visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0 on the left side you can switch Powershell versions and see where the parameter is present. PSv3 already has `-File` so this is a PSv2 question.

Comment: The one with Windows 7 sp1

Comment: It gets Folder A files then Folder B, can it be modified to makes them alternate, like a file from A then from B, then from A, ....

Comment: @user10191234 not in the same command. You have store the output in seperate variables and loop through them.

Answer (score 1):

The pre PSv3 way to check for file/directory is to inspect the `PSIsContainer` property in  a `Where-Object`

So this line will return:

```
PS A:\> Get-ChildItem -Path "Folder A","Folder B" |Where-object {!$_.PSIsContainer}| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
drinks.txt
food.txt
beverage.txt
entre.txt
```

Taking your question literal with double quotes and separated with `,`

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "Folder A","Folder B" |Where-object {!$_.PSIsContainer}|ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f $_.Name}) -join ', '
"drinks.txt", "food.txt", "beverage.txt", "entre.txt"
```

To have output sorted, just insert a `|Sort-Object Name`

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "Folder A","Folder B" |sort Name|Where-object {!$_.PSIsContainer}|ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f $_.Name}) -join ', '
"beverage.txt", "drinks.txt", "entre.txt", "food.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, but can it be made to alternate like I commented above

Comment: That is in fact a new question and should be asked as such. Note that comments to other answers will only seen by rereading. As @Paxz already mentioned  it will require a different approach.

Comment: Both approaches used above don't return headers, to put the output into a file you can use redirection `>`,`>>`, `Set-Content` or `Out-File`. to learn about the commands and parameters use `Get-Help cmdlet-name`. Otherwise new questions... BTW you should take the [tour] and read [ask]